# Ubuntu not able to launch citrix

Tags: citrix

I am trying to launch `citrix`, but the terminal shows the following error:

```
selfservice is unable to find a compatible webkit library and will now exit.
```

Does anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Comment: How did you install `citrix`?

Comment: Is this for the Citrix Receiver, or antoher Citrix product?

Comment: It's for Citrix Receiver 13.9.1 and  Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit. I installed using the process explained on Official website of Citrix.https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/receiver/linux/13-1/linux-install.html

Comment: These instructions resolved the same error for me. I got your error when I was using an older citrix download: https://wiki.debian.org/Citrix